Equivalence of Finding Negative Triangles in General and Tripartite Graphs
I consider the following two problems:
$\textbf{Negative Triangle}$
Given a weighted directed graph $G = (V, E, w)$ with $|V| = n$ and edge weights $w : E \to \{ -n^c, \ldots, n^c \}$ for some $c > 0$, determine if there exist three vertices $i, j, k$ where $i \neq j, j \neq k, i \neq k$ such that
$w(i, j) + w(j, k) + w(k, i) < 0$.
$\textbf{Negative Triangle'}$
Given a weighted, directed, and tripartite graph $G = (A \cup B \cup C, E, w)$ with $|A| = |B| = |C| = n$ and edge weights $w : E \to \{ -n^{c}, \ldots, n^{c} \}$ for some $c > 0$, determine if there exist three vertices $i \in A$, $j \in B$, $k \in C$ where $i \neq j, j \neq k, i \neq k$ such that
$w(i, j) + w(j, k) + w(k, i) < 0$.
I want to show that these problems are basically equivalent by proving that one can be reduced to the other, i.e., I want to show that $Negative Triangle' \leq Negative Triangle \leq Negative Triangle'$. Polynomial-time reduction is sufficient.
The reduction $Negative Triangle' \leq Negative Triangle$ is straightforward since $Negative Triangle'$ is a special case of $Negative Triangle$. For the other way I fail to come up with such reduction. In particular, I want to argue why we may assume without loss of generality that if we want to prove the existence of a negative triangle in any general graph $G$, we may assume that it is tripartite.

Please [edit] your question to clarify whether you require $i,j,k$ be pairwise disjoint (i.e., $i \ne j, j \ne k, k \ne i$).  Please clarify what kind of reduction you require.  Is a polynomial-time Turing reduction sufficient?
